# Foreign Key incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb

Al intentar añadir una clave foranea:

```
ALTER TABLE `concept_invoices` ADD CONSTRAINT `concept_invoices_article_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`article`) REFERENCES `articles`(`code`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Me da error de que uno de los campos esta mal configurado:

> Error de SQL (1005): Can't create table
>   `DATABASE`.`#sql-1440_a3` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed")

Esta es la tabla `concept_invoices` donde quiero añadir la clave foranea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta la tabla relacionada `articles`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los dos campos son VARCHAR(20) y las tablas innodb. ¿Que se me escapa?

Comment: Nope, las tablas estan vacias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según se, lo problemas pueden ser:

1) Que el campo referenciado contenga datos no compatibles con los fatos de la llave primaria ejemplo en la foránea tengas un números has el `10` y en la foránea tengas un `11`.

2) Que los tipos de datos usados en los campos sean incompartibles es decir, que en uno lo tengas tipo `varchar` y el otro `in`.

3) No tener el campo foráneo con un `index`.

**Creo que en este caso es donde cometes el pecado, ya que veo que en la estructura de la tabla en el campo `article` no le veo la definicion del `Index`**

antes de tratar de crear la referencia debes agregar el index asi:

```
CREATE INDEX "NOMBRE_ÍNDICE" ON "NOMBRE_TABLA" (NOMBRE_COLUMNA);
```

en tu caso seria...

```
CREATE INDEX "article_code" ON "articles" (code);
```

4) La llave a la que se referencia debe ser primaria (o unico), es decir en a tabla `articles` el campo `code` debe ser un campo primario,por que así se garantiza la legitimidad de la relación.

**Es decir si el campo `code` no cumple con estas caracteristicas, entonces puede surgir que en dicho campo puedas tener dos registros con el `code` # 1020, en este caso la foranea no sabria a cual de los dos apuntar**

Comment: He creado el indice asi: ALTER TABLE `concept_invoices` ADD INDEX `article` (`article`); pero no hay manera. Sigue dando error. He actualizado la imagen para que veais el indice creado.

Comment: Cuando creaste el index te genero algun error ?

Comment: Con la consulta de create index si. Quizas es por usar MariaDB, con la mia no.

Comment: Aun asi, el indice ya esta creado pero sigo teniendo el error :S

Comment: @50l3r mira bro, edite la pregunta y creo que alli resuleve tu problema

Comment: gracias por la ayuda y perdona la demora. Como ves, en esta otra tabla tengo dos claves foraneas pero ninguna de ellas son primarias o unicas: https://i.gyazo.com/84a6578fda6253dcc58310a5939d98a6.png

Comment: al parecer donde hay que crear el indice es en articles. Si quieres puedes modificar tu respuesta y la marco como correcta, Haciendo esto se soluciono el problema

Comment: Listo @50l3r bro ya la modifique la respuesta, y me alegro mucho hayas podido solucionar